# Whale-yeast Beer

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, liquor-beer, non-kosher-species

[This article](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thesalt/2014/07/15/331723450/captain-ahabs-revenge-brewing-beer-from-an-ancient-whale-bone) describes a beer created with yeast from fossilised remains of an ancient whale. From what I understand, the yeast imparts certain characteristics to the beer other than alcohol content. Would this affect its kashrut?

Comment: Sounds just like gelatin.

Comment: @DoubleAA, so a source for a machloket?

Comment: Serious question: If it's a fossil, is it still animal bones?
Fun question: If a fossil has been dated to before brias ha'olam (לפ"ק) is can it be treif?

Comment: from what I understand about yeast it isn't going to come from the bone but grow on top of it. That being said yeast is a bacteria and can grow anywhere. Not that all forms of yeast are useful in food products but they aren't from the things they are grown on. That being said most yeast for brewing is grown on malts.

Comment: @Dude, yeast is actually a fungus

Comment: Yes you are correct. I wrote incorectly when I said bacteria.

Comment: @Dude, no problem, I'm not a scientist.

Answer (score 2):

According to the article the yeast is from the swamp the bones were found in and is 'not nearly as old' as the bones.

I.e. the yeast just happened to be on the rescued bones and is an interesting hithertofore unknown subtype.

So it is not really Whale Bone Beer, just a gimmick.